# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)[related to sublime-text]

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, sublime-text

Every time I write command it shows me this error how do I solve it ? Error is related to coreutils , all the coreutils packeages are gone and rm command is also not working ? How to get the COREUTILS LIBRARY back .

```
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
[sudo] password for bhavuk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
sublime-text-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,184 kB of archives.
After this operation, 26.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package coreutils (--configure):
package coreutils is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
coreutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue with

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/coreutils_8.25-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Basically bypass apt and re-install coreutils directly then let apt figure out the rest.